# How to delete a columns duplicate cell value, and move up the other values in it's row

Tags: excel, duplicates

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have a column with many duplicate values. I would like to delete the duplicate cell values leaving only the top value, but at the same time move the the rows up like so:

[image]

Does anyone know what equation I would write to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove duplicates on the first column, by selecting the particular column and clicking on remove duplicates

1. Select the rest of the data
2. Press f5-->Special-->go to special dialog box appears
3. In the dialog box, check in 'Blanks' and Click ok
   You will see all blank cells selected. Right click and click on delete
4. You will have a option box. Select shift cells up
   Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is consistent i.e. values in left most column (as per your image) are repeated 5 times and is in `Column A` with corresponding values in `Column C` to `Column G`, try the following

In `Cell I2` enter the following formula

```
=OFFSET($A$2,FLOOR((ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2))*5,1),0)
```

Drag/Copy down as required

Then in `Cell J2` enter

```
=OFFSET($C$2,(COLUMN(C2)-COLUMN($C$2))+(ROW($C2)-ROW($C$2))*5,COLUMN(C2)-COLUMN($C$2))
```

Drag/Copy down as per data in `Column I` and across (to right) till `Column N`. See image for reference.

[image]

***Note :*** If any of the target cell is blank then result will show `0` as output.